# SOAP Service response is null

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I'm not getting any return response from the web service, input message XML is being received Ok.

Trying to get and return a custom XML conforming to an integration standard, that is why I'm using S.S.C.Message as a parameter.

```
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")]
public interface IHL7v3
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "PRPA_IN201301UV02", Action = "urn:hl7-org:v3:PRPA_IN201301UV02")]
    Message PIXManager_PRPA_IN201301UV02(Message input);
}

public class PIXService : IHL7v3
{
    public Message PIXManager_PRPA_IN201301UV02(Message input)
    {
         // this code is being reached and executing fine
         return Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap12, "Op", "Content"); // will be replaced by an actual XML text
    }
}
```

Service setup code:

```
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.2.120:31002/HL7Service");
        ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PIXService), baseAddress);

        selfHost.Description.Name = "PIXManager";
        selfHost.Description.Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3";

        try
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binder = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

            binder.Name = "PIXManager_Binding_Soap12";
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IHL7v3),
                binder,
                "PIX");

            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            Console.WriteLine(smb.HttpGetUrl);
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
              ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
              MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
              "mex"
            );

            selfHost.Open();
```

ideas why?

**Edit**:
Added ReplyAction, still no reply

```
[OperationContract(Name = "PRPA_IN201301UV02", Action = "urn:hl7-org:v3:PRPA_IN201301UV02", ReplyAction = "urn:hl7-org:v3:MCCI_IN000002UV01")]
// ..
return Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap12, "urn:hl7-org:v3:MCCI_IN000002UV01", "Something");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `MessageVersion` to `MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10`

```
return Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, "Op", "Content");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ReplyAction` of your operation is set to one value (I can't remember exactly which, but it's the default value), and you're creating the response message with an `Action` property of `Op`. Try setting the `ReplyAction` property in the `OperationContract`, and use the same value when creating the response message.

Comment: I've added ReplyAction, still no reply